# Should OAuth 2.0 be used for Authentication Timeouts?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

Developers of a mobile application are using the timeout period of OAuth 2.0 tokens to check when the application must re-authenticate with the server.

This conflicts with my understanding of the proper use of OAuth 2.0 tokens, although I am not exactly sure that I am correct.

My understanding:

OAuth is not about authentication but about authorization, e.g. can this device access some resource on a server on behalf of a user. Authentication logically precedes authorization and is about confirming the user is who they say they are.

So a user presents credentials (username and password) and the server authenticates that yes, this user is Bob.

The application Bob has logged into wants access to some resources on the server Bob has been authenticated to - say data from an API. So the application requests an OAuth token and it is granted, and one of its attributes is how long it exists. The application and the server exchange keys, and the data between the application and server is encrypted using the key.

An intruder reading the plaintext communication will not be able to decode it without the key. However, if an intruder is able to get the key they will be able to.

This is where the OAuth token end of life comes in. We don't want to use the same OAuth token (key) forever, because if an intruder was able to get that token they can decript our communication forever. If however, we refresh tokens every x hours, then they could decrepit the information only for x hours (let's say 2 hours).

I don't think the OAuth token expiration time should be connected with how long the user remains authenticated. That is simply up to the developers. In our case, if the user has some device security (a passcode for example), then we can let them remain authenticated for a long time (months for example). If they do not have device security then I want to force them to re-authenticate after a reasonable amount of time of inactivity, maybe 24 hours.

Is this correct or not, and if not, what parts.

Thanks in advance.

Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding on OAuth 2.0 is correct. In very abstract manner, the protocol define a way to obtain tokens, which can be used by a client to communicate against a protected endpoint.

[RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) mandate the usage of TLS when communicating with authorization server (the token obtaining) as well as when using it against an API/protected endpoint (Bearer token usage as defined in [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)). This protects token from in-transit attacks.

The OAuth access token is recommended to have a short life time. This is to avoid token stealing as well as token misusing that can be done by client. You can read more about best practices from [RFC6819](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819). Access token lifetime specifics can be read from [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-3.1.2).

Now about selecting the correct life time. As you already figured out, using a refresh token is the desired approach to renew access tokens instead of having a long lasting access tokens. For example, a refresh token can be valid for few days while access token valid only for few hours.

But be mindful about the following,

**+** Whether your application can obtain and secure a refresh token

For example, SPA cannot obtain a refresh token as it cannot store it for extended time. In such case you need to look for alternative mechanisms to renew the access token.

**+** Is access token used against external domain

Using access token toward an external API increase the threat vector. For example, if you have a closed system (client and backend in one domain) then you may think of increasing access token life time. But not for an extended period like 24hours.!

**+** Single sign on (SSO)

Instead of using long lasting access tokens, you can get the help of authorization server to maintain an SSO behavior on top of browser. This is similar to "remember me" you observe in modern login dialogs. Once logged in, browser maintain a cookie which lasts for some time (ex:- A week). The next time you use OAuth token obtaining flow, your authorisations server detect this logged in state, hence skipping login dialog. Of course, such approach must be decided on exact security/policy requirements.

In conclusion, use access tokens with reduced life time.Using refresh token is the desired approach for token renewal. But depending on the situation, you can choose alternatives as well.